# Avoid Visual Studio to change property

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a class with various elements and I want to assign a setting to a property, like:

```
this.MyProccess.StartInfo.FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting;
```

The problem is that when closing VisualStudio it auto change the setting to the setting value.

```
this.MyProccess.StartInfo.FileName = "MySetting Default Value";
```

How can I make to stay as the first one?

Comment: When changing the Settings did you call `Save` ?

Comment: If `MyProcess.FileName` is a variable it is only Runtime constant. When you stop your Program all the variables will be flushed

Comment: @Nudity Yes I saved the settings. The FileName is a ProcessStartInfo property I setted up in Designer.cs. I added the Process component to the WPF via Toolbox.